# Angular page does not load if query is added (ftp server)

Tags: angular, url, routes, ionos

I published a build on a ftp server (ionos).
The navigating works fine.

**Problem:**

If I am now in one of the subpages of the build and I want to reload the page it only works if there are no query parameters. On the start page it works.

> [https://test.com/subpage?query={"b":true}](https://test.com/subpage?query=%7B%22b%22:true%7D)

**This is the answer:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a client side routing problem with Apache. Try this and add a `.htaccess` in your server root context.

```
# check that mod_negotiation is enabled
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    # diable MultiViews to prevent the Apache behavior of indexing a directory
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

# check that mod_rewrite is enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # enable the runtime rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # stop processing any other rule set if index.html is requested
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

    # route everything else to /index.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Further description look at IONOS [Deploy NOW](https://docs.ionos.space/docs/apache-configuration-htaccess/#templating-htaccess)